# Error on csv file importing to datagridview in vb. Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have code to import csv and excel file into datagridview using in vb.Net.which is working fine in developing machine(Have windows 7 32bit). When I publish my project and installed on another machine (having windows 7 64bit) csv file could not be importd. Shows error like odbc driver. I have installed iterop and accessdatabaseengine.what's an issue with it?

Need code to import csv file in windows 7 64 and windows 10 machine

Comment: I  published it as anycpu

Comment: But, in same project importing from excel is working fine in windows 7 64bit..but not in windows 10

Comment: Without the code example you probably should add to your question, we're only guessing.  Would suggest that the problem is you're using either the 64 or 32 bit ODBC driver while your target machine is having the opposite.  Ensure your building using the correct app bitness or your target has the required ODBC driver version.  Of course, there are a number of libraries that exist that significantly simplify csv file handling without the overheads of ODBC

Comment: Dim connString As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" _
                    & csvFileFolder & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""

                Dim conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(connString)

                'Open a data adapter, specifying the file name to load
                Dim daa As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & csvFileName & "]", conn)
                'Then fill a data table, which can be bound to a grid
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                daa.Fill(dt)

Comment: Please refer my code

Comment: Well, again going back to the app 64/32 bit thing.  You say you've installed the access database engine.  Di you install the 64 bit version or the 32bit version?  Not sure what version of access you're targeting here but, on the downloads, there is accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe.  Are you sure that wasn't already installed on your Win7 machine where it is working?

Comment: Totally uninstalled and installed 32 bit version and published my project as 32 bit mode. It's working fine now. Thank you